# Can I take the mediant of two sides of an inequality?

Tags: inequality

I have an inequality where I have:

$$
\frac{a}{c}>\frac{b}{d}
$$

Would the above inequality imply:

$$
\frac{a+p}{c+q}>\frac{b+p}{d+q}
$$

My question is whether the first inequality would imply that the second inequality is true. In other words, given $\frac{a}{c}>\frac{b}{d}$, would adding an integer $p$ to the numerators $a$ and $b$ and adding an integer $q$ to the denominators $c$ and $d$ still make the inequality hold true? If not are there any specific constraints to any of the variables where the inequality still holds true? I tried to cross-multiply the second inequality, but I couldn't figure anything out.

Comment: What is a "mediant"?

Comment: Not true in general.  You can just cross multiply, use your given inequality and derive conditions on $p$ and $q$

Comment: For example take $a=3$, $b=5$, $c=2$, $d=4$, $p=1$ and $q=3$. $\frac{3}{2}>\frac{5}{4}$ but $\frac{4}{5}=\frac{3+1}{2+3}<\frac{5+1}{4+3}=\frac{6}{7}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do it step-by-step.

Suppose $\dfrac{a}{c}>\dfrac{b}{d}$

Let's try to examine $$\dfrac{a+p}{c}  \;\  \stackrel{\Large ?}{>} \;\ \  \dfrac{b+p}{d}$$

You can cross-multiply and derive that this is only true if $ad-bc > p(c-d)$

Next, let's try to examine
$$\dfrac{a}{c+q}  \;\  \stackrel{\Large ?}{>} \;\ \  \dfrac{b}{d+q}$$

You can cross-multiply and derive that this is only true if $ad-bc > q(b-a)$

Thus, your inequality is not always true. 
For conditions when it is true: **cross-multiply and derive!**